# How to automatically link back in Sphinx/RST?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using Sphinx for creating docs. Many times I have to cross reference sections, for example when I write about **Destruction of Known World**, I'd like to reference to **Schemes of an Atom Bomb** here and there. This is easy via regular cross reference. But when I decide that atom bomb would be to easily blocked by some countries, I'd like to conveniently track every usage of it's schemes and check if I can replace it to **DIY: Brewing Deadly Virus**. I don't want to manually add reference back from **Schemes of an Atom Bomb** to every paragraph in **Destruction of known World** that talks (and references to) the schemes. I'd like it to be automatically generated. How can I do that?

Short: I would like to add cross references from A to B, and magically have references from B to A somewhere near B.

Comment: For mighty devs - yes. For civil users on Windows: "what?" ;]